# How can I save a PDF file in chrome that is the response to a one-time POST request?

Tags: google-chrome, pdf

I've had a bunch of cases where PDF files were generated for me in response to a POST request, including a token valid for exactly one request.

I can read these PDFs fine in the browser, but if I hit refresh I get served a page telling me that my token expired, as expected.

If I hit the download button or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> in the chrome PDF viewer, it fails like this:

[image]

Clearly, it's sending a second request for the document, even though it already has it.

How can I actually save this PDF to my computer?

Comment: What happens if you press control-S?  That seems to save pages in Chromium.

Comment: Same problem - it triggers a page refresh before saving

Comment: Can you find it in your temporary files?  It has to be downloaded somewhere in order to display it to you.

Comment: @DDay: Indeed, but it might never make it to disk. I'll have a look.

Comment: I would clear my cache first for ease of checking.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to go to print window by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd> and then in destination(in left pane) click change and select save as PDF

NOTE: Steps as per google chrome browser

Comment: That does the trick, but removes the navigation outline from the PDF

Comment: I am afraid but the only choice left is simple screenshot or full page screenshot but I Hope i am wrong